# Trino CLI fails to receive data from server

Tags: presto, trino

I have setup Trino 433 on an Ubuntu server and it appears to be running as expected, but when connected to it using the Trino CLI `trino-cli-433-executable.jar` from my workstation, the CLI tool never receives results from the server.

- I can connect to the server using a browser and get the Cluster Overview.  This UI all appears to work fine.
- The CLI connects to the server from my workstation, and I see some activity in the Cluster Overview as it is connection.
- When I submit a query to the server (say, `SHOW TABLES;`) from the CLI, I see it come up as running in the Cluster Overview.  The Cluster Overview UI then shows it as complete, but the CLI hangs, never recieving the result.
- The same CLI actions when running the CLI directly on the server return the list of tables.

I'm assuming this is a networking/firewall/security issue.  It's not affecting the Web UI, so something about those responses is different, but I can't find out any info on the CLI receiving responses - is it expecting a callback, opening a return port for the response, etc?

Can anyone help with this or point me to a solution?  I need to go to the networking guys with some guidance.